# Is there really no use for MD5 anymore?

Tags: hash, md5

I read [an article about password schemes](http://web.archive.org/web/20130407190430/http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html) that makes two seemingly conflicting claims:

> MD5 is broken; it’s too slow to use as a general purpose hash; etc
>
> The problem is that MD5 is fast

I know that MD5 should not be used for password hashing, and that it also should not be used for integrity checking of documents.  There are way too many sources citing MD5 preimaging attacks and MD5s low computation time.

However, I was under the impression that MD5 still can be used as a non-cryptgraphic hash function:

1. Identifying malicious files, such as when [Linux Mint's download servers were compromised and an ISO file was replaced by a malicious one](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/pay-attention-linux-mint-173-isos-were-hacked-on-20th-february-check-if-you-are-infected-or-not); in this case you want to be sure that your file **doesn't** match; collision attacks aren't a vector here.
2. Finding duplicate files.  By MD5-summing all files in a directory structure it's easy to find identical hashes.  The seemingly identical files can then be compared in full to check if they are really identical.  Using SHA512 would make the process slower, and since we compare files in full anyway there is no risk in a potential false positive from MD5. (In a way, this would be creating a rainbow table where all the files are the dictionary)

There are checksums of course, but from my experience, the likelihood of finding two different files with the same MD5 hash is very low as long as we can rule out foul play.

When the password scheme article states that "MD5 is fast", it clearly refers to the problem that hashing MD5 is too cheap when it comes to hashing a large amount of passwords to find the reverse of a hash.  But what does it mean when it says that "[MD5 is] too slow to use as a general purpose hash"?  Are there faster standardized hashes to compare files, that still have a reasonably low chance of collision?

Comment: The collision attack is the problem, however, MD5 still has pre-image resistance.

Comment: _"Using SHA512 would make the process slower ..."_ - On my system, `openssl speed` reports 747MB/s for MD5, and 738MB/s for SHA-512, so that's barely a difference ;)

Comment: I believe MD5 can still be used as a [PRF](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/57656/29925).

Comment: For longer files on amd64 processors with optimized implementations, I think SHA-512 is one of the faster hashing algorithms ([faster than SHA-256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/sha512-faster-than-sha256) as the type sizes are easier to manipulate).

Comment: Fun fact: There's still a use for MD4 on millions of devices. The popular ext4 filesystem in Linux uses half-MD4 internally to generate a hash tree. I'm sure there are plenty of other uses too, even for MD5.

Comment: There's still one major use for MD5: compatibility with legacy software that expects MD5.

Comment: I think it is important to ask for the context. If you look at existing software, in some cases there is no urgent need to replace MD5 (namely of you need security *and* it depends on preimages resistance). However, if you are writing new software, there is not a single reason to use MD5 or SHA-1 over current state-of-the-art - regardless of your security assumptions.

Comment: There's still a use for bit parity as well... what is your point? MD5 is sub-optimal for many purposes now, a big selling point was it being secure in the 90s/00s. It's designed to be cryptographic. And it's also designed for 32-bit processors.

Comment: @bryc Today, blake3 runs circles around MD5, even on 32bit cpus - and blake2s (not 2b but 2s) is faster than md5 on 32bit cpus, sooo

Comment: @hanshenrik If you read carefully, I was not praising MD5 or saying it was fast. But yes `blake2s` is a good replacement for 32-bit archs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I know that MD5 should not be used for password hashing, and that it also should not be used for integrity checking of documents. There are way too many sources citing MD5 preimaging attacks and MD5s low computation time.

There is no published *preimage* attack on MD5 that is cheaper than a generic attack on any 128-bit hash function.  But you shouldn't rely on that alone when making security decisions, because cryptography is tricky and adversaries are clever and resourceful and can find ways around it!

> 1. Identifying malicious files, such as when [Linux Mint's download servers were compromised and an ISO file was replaced by a malicious one](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/pay-attention-linux-mint-173-isos-were-hacked-on-20th-february-check-if-you-are-infected-or-not); in this case you want to be sure that your file **doesn't** match; collision attacks aren't a vector here.

The question of whether to publish known-good *vs.* known-bad hashes after a compromise is addressed [elsewhere](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70056)—in brief, there's not much that publishing known-bad hashes accomplishes, and according to the citation, Linux Mint published known-good, not known-bad, hashes.  So what security do you get from known-good MD5 hashes?

There are two issues here:

1. **If you got the MD5 hash from the *same source* as the ISO image, there's nothing that would prevent an adversary from replacing *both* the MD5 hash *and* the ISO image.**

   To prevent this, you and the Linux Mint curators need *two* channels: one for the hashes which can't be compromised (but need only have very low bandwidth), and another for the ISO image (which needs high bandwidth) on which you can then *use* the MD5 hash in an attempt to detect compromise.

   There's another way to prevent this: Instead of using the uncompromised channel for the hash of *every* ISO image over and over again as time goes on—which means more and more opportunities for an attacker to subvert it—use it *once* initially for a public key, which is then used to *sign* the ISO images; then there's only one opportunity for an attacker to subvert the public key channel.
2. **Even if you got the MD5 hash from a *known-good* source, collision attacks may still be a vector in cases like this.**  Consider the following scenario:

   - I am an *evil* developer.  I write two software packages, whose distributions *collide* under MD5.  One of the packages is benign and will survive review and audit.  The other one will surreptitiously replace your family photo album by erotic photographs of sushi.
   - The Linux Mint curators carefully scrutinize and audit everything they publish in their package repository and publish the MD5 hashes of *what they have audited* in a public place that I can't compromise.
   - The Linux Mint curators cavalierly administer the package distributions in their package repository, under the false impression that the published MD5 hashes will protect users.

   In this scenario, **I can replace the benign package by the erotic sushi package, pass the MD5 verification with flying colors, and give you a nasty—and luscious—surprise when you try to look up photos of that old hiking trip you took your kids on.**

> 2. Finding duplicate files.  By MD5-summing all files in a directory structure it's easy to find identical hashes.  The seemingly identical files can then be compared in full to check if they are really identical.  Using SHA512 would make the process slower, and since we compare files in full anyway there is no risk in a potential false positive from MD5.

When I put my benign software package and my erotic sushi package, which collide under MD5, in your directory, your duplicate-detection script will initially think they are duplicates.  In this case, you *absolutely must* compare the files in full.  **But there are much better ways to do this!**

- If you use SHA-512, you can safely skip the comparison step.  Same if you use BLAKE2b, which can be even faster than MD5.
- You could even use MD5 safely for this *if* you use it as HMAC-MD5 under a uniform random key, and safely skip the comparison step.  HMAC-MD5 does not seem to be broken, as a pseudorandom function family—so it's probably fine for security, [up to the birthday bound](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59411), but there are better faster PRFs like keyed BLAKE2 that won't raise any auditors' eyebrows.
- Even better, you can choose a random key and hash the files with a universal hash under the key, like Poly1305.  This is *many times faster* than MD5 or BLAKE2b, and the probability of a collision between any two files is less than $1/2^{100}$, so the probability of collision among $n$ files is less than $\binom n 2 2^{-100}$ and thus you can still safely skip the comparison step until you have quadrillions of files.
- You could also just use a cheap checksum like a CRC with a fixed polynomial.  This will be the fastest of the options—far and away faster than MD5—but unlike the previous options you still absolutely must compare the files in full.

**So, is MD5 safe for finding *candidate* duplicates to verify, if you subsequently compare the files bit by bit in full?  Yes.  So is the constant zero function.**

> (In a way, this would be creating a rainbow table where all the files are the dictionary)

**This is not a rainbow table.**  A rainbow table is a [specific technique](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45146-4_36) for precomputing a random walk over a space of, say, passwords, via, say, MD5 hashes, in a way that can find MD5 preimages for hashes that *aren't* necessarily in your table with fewer trial hash evaluations than a naive search.  (It can also be [done in parallel with the search](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce) to not only speed it up but reduce the price/performance ratio.)  It is not simply a list of precomputed hashes on a dictionary of inputs.

(The [blog post by tptacek in 2007](http://web.archive.org/web/20130407190430/http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html) that you cited, and the [blog post by Jeff Atwood](https://web.archive.org/web/20130324055553/http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.html) that it was a response to, both misrepresent what rainbow tables are.  tptacek [claims in 2019](https://twitter.com/tqbf/status/1169339634033287168) that he DGAF about rainbow tables, perhaps because modern password hashes thwart them by the mere use of salts.  But password search under a fixed, unsalted hash function is only one application of the idea, for which the term was popularized.  Rainbow tables are relevant to *any* preimage search as noted in the [original paper](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45146-4_36), such as AES keys given known plaintext/ciphertext pairs.  And it's not just a trivial time/memory tradeoff—a rainbow table preimage search can [reduce price/performance ratio if parallelized](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce).  This is why, for instance, AES-128 should not be construed to give ‘128-bit security’.)

> When the password scheme article states that "MD5 is fast", it clearly refers to the problem that hashing MD5 is too cheap when it comes to hashing a large amount of passwords to find the reverse of a hash.  But what does it mean when it says that "[MD5 is] too slow to use as a general purpose hash"?  Are there faster standardized hashes to compare files, that still have a reasonably low chance of collision?

I don't know what tptacek meant—you could email and ask—but if I had to guess, I would guess this meant it's awfully slow for things like hash tables, where you would truncate MD5 to a few bits to determine an index into an array of buckets or an open-addressing array.

Comment: Why does selecting a different hash algorithm eliminate the risk of collisions (sushi bullet)?

Comment: @chrylis Nobody has ever published any way to find SHA-512 or BLAKE2b collisions, nor even, say, SHA-256 collisions.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a hash function and a cheap checksum? Are just functions design with different trade offs in mind?

Comment: @Alexander ‘Hash function’ means many things, and is usually some approximation to a uniform random choice of function in some context (random oracle model, pseudorandom function family, pseudorandom _permutation_ family, _etc._).  A ‘checksum’ is used for some error-detecting capability; _e.g._, a well-designed 32-bit CRC is _guaranteed_ to detect any 1-bit errors and usually guarantees detecting some larger number of bit errors in certain data word sizes, while a 32-bit truncation of SHA-256 might fail to detect some 1-bit errors.  The terms are generally used quite loosely, however.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage "CRC is guaranteed to detect any 1-bit errors and usually guarantees detecting some larger number of bit errors in certain data word sizes, while a 32-bit truncation of SHA-256 might fail to detect some 1-bit errors. " woah. That's really powerful, and really cool. I didn't know that. I'll read more into it!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the Linux Mint case. They published the MD5 hash of the *infected* ISO after they recovered from the hack, so that people can check whether the ISO they installed from was infected. Your sushi story seems to imply that you thought MD5 was used to prove the integrity of the original uninfected ISO file. This was not the case.

Comment: @jornane The story at http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/pay-attention-linux-mint-173-isos-were-hacked-on-20th-february-check-if-you-are-infected-or-not gives what it claims are known _good_ hashes, not known _bad_ hashes.  After all, why would you say ‘_this_ hash is bad’ when the adversary could flip a single bit and get a completely different hash—not understood to be bad—for a nevertheless malicious ISO image?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Because they already removed the infected files at that point, but they needed to allow users to check the files downloaded on the users' hard drives, USB sticks and DVDs. The adversary at that point had already lost access to the server and was therefore unable to flip any bit, neither did the adversary have access to the computers used to download the infected ISO. Therefore, users could use MD5 to check whether their copy was infected; if it matched the infected ISOs MD5, they know not to use it, and to wipe any machine it was installed on.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage It seems you are correct in that they only published the *correct* hashes and not the *infected* hashes. I really remembered it the other way around. I still believe that MD5 could be used here because the bad file had become immutable by the time the hash was published, but I'm still intreged by this, so I will ask a separate question about it. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70056/

Comment: @jornane Can you clarify whether you're saying Linux Mint published known _good_ ISOs or known _bad_ ISOs?  The source you cited says: ‘If your ISO's MD5 matches with the below valid signatures then your ISO is original otherwise it is hacked one and you should delete it immediately.’  If you distribute _known bad_ hashes, the adversary could just distribute many different versions of the ISO—maybe a different one for each download!

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage In my memory, they published the MD5 hash of the *bad* ISO in their blog post, and MD5 hashes of *good* ISOs on their FTP server, but I see that that memory is wrong. It's what I thought when writing the question. It's getting off-topic for this question, so I made a new question about this. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70056/

Comment: @jornane Maybe I'm playing the long game.  1. Find an MD5 collision with the sushi.  2. On _one_ compromised server, upload a package that is malicious but in an obvious way that will be easy to detect and cause a ruckus.  3. Everyone flips out and makes sure they use the good package's hash—which, as it happens, is also the sushi package's hash—and so they all _simultaneously_ stampede to update their software.  4. The long tentacles of nigiri now lurk.

Comment: "two channels" - such as my webpage for the hashes, and bitTorrent for the file itself? (note I'd still use SHA1 in such a case)

Comment: @JohnDvorak How do you distribute the torrent file?  If it's on the same web page, that doesn't help.  The distinction with _signatures_ is that I can publish my public key _today_, and as long as you download it _today_, it doesn't matter if the adversary can compromise my web server _tomorrow_ to distribute a forged distribution: you already have my public key today so you can detect the forgery tomorrow.  (Don't use SHA-1 either!  [SHA-1 is broken too.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60655/49826)  Use SHA-2, SHA-3, or BLAKE2.)

Comment: Answer by Thomas Ptacek (tqbf on twitter, tptacek on HN): https://twitter.com/tqbf/status/1169339634033287168

Answer (score 10):

> But what does it mean when it says that "[MD5 is] too slow to use as a general purpose hash"? Are there faster standardized hashes to compare files, that still have a reasonably low chance of collision?

[BLAKE2](http://www.blake2.net/) is faster than MD5 and currently known to provide 64-bit collision resistence when truncated to the same size as MD5 (compare <30 of that of MD5).

Answer (score 6):

There's not a compelling reason to use MD5; however, there are some embedded systems with a MD5 core that was used as a stream verifier.   In those systems, MD5 is still used.  They are moving to BLAKE2 because it's smaller in silicon, and it has the benefit of being faster than MD5 in general.

The reason that MD5 started fall out of favor with hardware people was that the word reordering of the MD5 message expansions seems to be simple, but actually
they require a lot of circuits for demultiplexing and interconnect, and the hardware efficiencies are greatly degraded compared to BLAKE. In contrast, the message expansion blocks for BLAKE algorithms can be efficiently implemented as simple feedback shift registers.

The BLAKE team did a nice job of making it work well on silicon and in instructions.

*edit*: SHA-1, SHA-2, etc also look pretty nice in circuits.

Comment: I did not know about BLAKE, this seems interesting. I assumed from the post that there would be some hashing system that would not be cryptographically secure to be faster that MD5, but it seems BLAKE has managed to be the best of both worlds. I’m considering this answer as the accepted one, but I’ll wait a few days while there is activity around this question.

Comment: @jornane Squeamish Ossifrage has a better answer.  I just wanted to mention the hardware side of things.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about intentional attacks on the hash, then you don't need a cryptographic hash at all. There are some algorithms that are very, very fast and provide excellent collision resistance for *most*, data, but **not for intentional attacks**. Take a look at xxhash.

Comment: Non-cryptographic hashes can be vulnerable to _accidental_ collisions if the input has certain properties. A cryptographic hash ensures those properties are extremely unlikely to come about by chance.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that MD5 should not be used for password hashing

Indeed. However, that's about the direct applicability of MD5 to a password or to use it with just a password and salt. In that case MD5 is less secure than a dedicated password hash with a work factor, at least for common passwords and pass phrases.

However, the use of MD5 within a PRF (HMAC) and *within a password hash* is still OK as it relies on pre-image resistance for security, rather than collision resistance.

I'd rather not bet that MD5 stays secure for pre-image resistance though. Attacks only get better and although I don't see any progress on breaking MD5's pre-image resistance, I would not rule it out either.

> Identifying malicious files, such as when Linux Mint's download servers were compromised and an ISO file was replaced by a malicious one; in this case you want to be sure that your file doesn't match; collision attacks aren't a vector here.

MD5 is still secure to check hashes from another server *as long as hackers cannot alter the input of the MD5 hash*. However, for something like a full ISO, I'd say that they would have plenty of opportunity bringing in binary files that seem innocent with regard to contents, while they alter the intermediate state of MD5 vulnerable to collision attacks.

That was not the attack that you referred to; in that case the MD5 hash on the official server *was* different from the one calculated over the ISO image.

But attack on file distribution **do** rely on collision resistance, and this kind of use case *can definitely be attacked*. It would probably not be all that easy (correctly lining up the binary data required for the attack at the start of the ISO and such), but it is a vector of attack none-the-less.

The same goes for SHA-1 in Git by the way. Not easy to breach, but far from impossible, whatever Linus says.

> Finding duplicate files. By MD5-summing all files in a directory structure it's easy to find identical hashes. The seemingly identical files can then be compared in full to check if they are really identical. Using SHA512 would make the process slower, and since we compare files in full anyway there is no risk in a potential false positive from MD5. (In a way, this would be creating a rainbow table where all the files are the dictionary)

Sure, if there is no possibility of attack or if you compare the files fully anyway then MD5 is fine.

However, *if* there is a vector of attack then you *need* to perform a full binary compare even after the hash has matched. Otherwise an attacker could make you retrieve the wrong deduplicated file. If you'd use a cryptographically strong hash then you would not have to perform the full file comparison *at all*. As others have noticed, a 256-512 bit hash is a lot easier to handle than performing a full file compare when storing. Passing over the file twice is not very fast either; all the speed advantages of MD5 are very likely nullified by the I/O required.

Besides that, if you would *reference* it using the hash then there is no comparison to be made; you would only have a single file (this **is** about deduplication after all).

> "[MD5 is] too slow to use as a general purpose hash"? Are there faster standardized hashes to compare files, that still have a reasonably low chance of collision?

Others have already mentioned keyed hashes (Message Authentication Codes) and non-crypto hashes, and one or two *really* fast crypto hashes that are more secure and usually as fast as MD5. But yes, as cryptographic hashes go, MD5 is certainly rather fast. That's mainly because it is uncomplicated and because it has a small state / output size.

As we found out, MD5 is *so* uncomplicated that it could be broken. Other algorithms such as SHA-256 and -512 largely rely on the same principles but are still deemed secure. Note that newer Intel and AMD processors have SHA-256 acceleration, so it is likely that they would perform similarly to MD5 *if* the hardware acceleration is indeed used.

---

As you can see, MD5 is almost *never* is a good idea, and many (smart) people still believe MD5 or SHA-1 to be secure under "their specific circumstances". They can often be proven wrong and leave the door open for (future) attacks on the system. I'd try to avoid it under any circumstances, especially if it is not used within HMAC.

What I also see is that it is defended because a system cannot be upgraded. MD5 has been under attack for years and years. If you still cannot migrate away from MD5 then there is something *seriously* wrong with the security of your system that transcends the use of MD5. If you're designing / programming or *keeping* systems without upgrade path then you're the main security hazard, not the hash algorithm.

Comment: There's no modern password hash that uses MD5.  One could instantiate PBKDF2 with HMAC-MD5, but I'm not sure I've ever seen anyone do that, and if one is making a custom choice to begin with, one might as well choose a modern password hash!

Comment: I'm very prolific on SO, I've seen it plenty of times. People know MD5 and for some reason like to use it.

Comment: > MD5 is still secure to check hashes from another server _as long as hackers cannot alter the input of the MD5 hash_.  $$$$  This requires very careful qualification.  The issue about how much control an attacker might have over the input is extremely subtle and not obvious if you're not very familiar with cryptography.  See the story at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70057 where the attacker doesn't change anything at the time the initial compromise is detected but still compromises everyone in the end even if they verify the good MD5 hashes.

Comment: Well, that was kind of the point of my answer, you think you're secure, but you're not.  What you posted is an interesting attack vector, but it still relies on the adversary (or one of his companions, same thing in a theoretic sense) to control the input of the hash.

Answer (score 1):

A case where the use of the MD5-hash would still make sense (and low risk of deleting duplicated files):

If you want to find duplicate files you can just use [CRC32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

As soon as two files return the same CRC32-hash you recompute the files with MD5 hash. If the MD5 hash is again identical for both files then you know that the files are duplicates.

---

In a case of high risk by deleting files:

**You want the process to be fast:** Instead use a hash function that's not vulnerable for a second hash of the files, i.e. [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) or [SHA3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3). It's *extremely* unlikely that these hashes would return an identical hash.

**Speed is no concern:** Compare the files byte per byte.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92946/discussion-on-answer-by-aleksanderras-is-there-really-no-use-for-md5-anymore).

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is currently used throughout the world both at home and in the enterprise.  It's the file change mechanism within *nix's [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) if you opt for something other than changed timestamp detection.  It's used for backup, archiving and file transfer between in-house systems.  Even between enterprises over VPNs.

Your comment that it *"should not be used for integrity checking of documents"* is interesting, as that's kinda what is done when transferring files (aka documents).  A hacked file/document is philosophically a changed file/document. If on a source system an attacker changes a document in a smart way to produce the same MD5 hash, it will not propagate onward to the target system as the document has not changed in rsync's eyes.  As  colliding hashes can be  found quickly now, a carefully made change can go unnoticed by rsync, and (niche) attacks can occur.

So if you ask *"Is there really no use for MD5 anymore?"*, an answer is that it's in current and widespread use at home and in the enterprise.

In rsync's case, swapping out MD5 to something faster would only produce marginal overall speed improvement given storage and networking overheads. It would certainly  be less than the simple ratio of hash rates suggests.

Comment: I think librsync actually uses BLAKE2 now.

Comment: BLAKE2b is 512, BLAKE2s is 256. It can be truncated though, of course.

Comment: @forest Well you sound convincing,  though man pages say MD5 and the hash is 32 hex characters.  What would be the reason for truncation?

Comment: Truncation can be done to retain compatibility with the protocol. If the protocol is designed for a 128-bit hash, then it's simpler to truncate a larger hash than to change the protocol (possibly adding more overhead to something designed to minimize overhead). I'm not sure if it uses BLAKE2 the same way it used MD5, but I do know that it was "replacing MD5 with BLAKE2". The code has been added to librsync.

Comment: See https://github.com/librsync/librsync/issues/5 and https://github.com/librsync/librsync/blob/dfba8988ef12d6a2f96dc16e608923a9a5d6371d/src/sumset.c#L121.

Comment: @forest All that codey stuff sounds hard, but I think that `if (protocol_version >= 30) return CSUM_MD5;` in https://download.samba.org/pub/unpacked/rsync/checksum.c calls https://download.samba.org/pub/unpacked/rsync/lib/md5.c.  It seems to be self contained. Perhaps you have a different version of rsync?  Even if not, any changes must be pretty recent so there'll still be a lot of MD5 out there...

Comment: I was linking to librsync, which provides the backend.

Answer (score -1):

One of the things not mentioned here, is that the attraction of hashing algorithms, (like programming languages etc) is *ubiquity*. The 'reason' for using MD5 is:

- everyone knows about it
- it's implemented for pretty much every combination of architectures, OSs, programming languages etc
- it's limitations are well understood.

This is important both from a practicality and security point of view.
It reasonable to expect someone to be able to handle it (practicality) and it helps devs audit the process and not skip steps because they are 'tricky' (security).

All that said, SHA is catching up and I think in time MD5 will die out, and when it does so, it will be quite quickly. Because its only a self-fulfilling-prophecy that it is popular in the first place, as there are normally better choices.

However, in the intervening time, that its widely adopted may well be a good reason in it own right to use MD5 (within it's limits).

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - I think there are some additions that would improve this answer: It seems like the bullet points are equally applicable to SHA1/SHA2 (considering that they're standardized algorithms). It is clear why those points would promote the use of *an* algorithm, but it's not clear to me why they would promote the use of MD5 over SHA1/SHA2. The last point seems to say that "everyone else is doing it" is a good enough reason to use MD5 (which is seldom a good reason to do anything). It also mentions limits, but does not elaborate on what those limits should be.

Comment: On a separate point: `it helps devs audit the process and not skip steps because they are 'tricky' (security).` - Use of MD5 will immediately make a competent auditor skeptical of the quality of engineering that went into the program that uses it. This is a huge reason not to use MD5: Even if it does not create an exploitable weakness, it is a big red flag that casts doubt on the programs quality and the cryptographic knowledge of the developers.

Comment: **Use of MD5 has been questionable for a _quarter of a century_** since Hans Dobbertin published collisions in the compression function in 1996, and **MD5 has been _completely broken_ for a decade and a half** since Xiaoyun Wang's team demonstrated collisions in 2004.  Collisions in MD5 were _exploited in practice_ by the United States and Israel to sabotage Iran's nuclear program.  SHA-2 has been available since 2002, seventeen years.  Note SHA-0 and SHA-1 are broken too; [timeline](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60655/49826).  $$$$ The Caesar cipher meets all your criteria too.

Comment: Just too be clear: I don't think MD5 is better than SHA-2 (or good). The question was not 'which is better' but is there _any_ reason to use MD5. Sure, the 17 years that SHA-2 has had to take over and is widely enough used that it's a good choice. Especially if you're the internet connected windows/linux space. If that's where you are and there's no special cases then don't use MD5 there are better alternatives. But that wan not the question. It take a while to become trusted and some tech stacks move a lot less rapidly. Sometimes 17 years isn't that long.

Comment: If someone is (a) actually designing a protocol (b) constrained to a specific, real environment that is (c) limited to MD5 in that environment for specific technical reasons that can be articulated, then they can ask a question in which we give useful guidance for security.  That's not the case here: the original poster is asking about convenience, about an _ad hoc_ vulnerability disclosure on highly capable computers that can easily use SHA-2, about cheap ways to keep collision probabilities low, _etc._

Comment: This is important because random people on the internet who _do not_ have such constraints will find invariably this site by web searches and follow its guidance, and in the absence of clear evidence that naive use of MD5 can be dangerous—to the point that even in a _professional system of code signing_ it directly enabled international industrial sabotage of Iran's nuclear program—they will easily justify the use of MD5 to themselves and sit happy in their tribal wisdom that MD5 isn't really all that bad after all in insufferable Hackernews threads.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Sure but that wasn't the question. Also if your looking for hashing advice and your research is: Read one crypto.stackexchange Q/A titled: "Is there really no use for MD5 anymore?", scroll past most of the answers that say 'dont do it' and get to the one that says "well for completeness's sake: maybe", and take that to mean MD5 for the win... On that note, there'd be fewer of those hackernews posts if there wasn't a legit argument to say people had been overly negative. I think honesty about its weakness is better than scaring people away.

Comment: Maybe if cryptographers were a little more conciliatory toward bad advice, Hackernews would be less inclined to shoot people in the foot out of spite?