# Understanding Hash collisions - why bad?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256, sha-1, collision-attack

I read few answers about the question: why are hash collisions so dangerous?
But did not get a really satisfying answer.
Assume we are the first people who found a SHA256-collision, like

sha256($§"%fa7asd8ft6sds) = sha256(889=?`/&&%"HSF)

(this is not a real equation, but assume it is true).

Why is this dangerous? Why is SHA256 broken now? How do I get more collisions out of this? And maybe more important collisions like sha256(Send me 5€) = sha256(Send me 5000€ &%$"§"%§%...)

Comment: If I sign a hash of message A, then the ability to find a hash collision would mean that you could claim that I signed message B instead, because they would share the same hash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are other good attack examples that use the hash collision?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87104/what-are-other-good-attack-examples-that-use-the-hash-collision)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, cryptographic hash collisions are not found by searching or by chance. They are computed because - for some reason - the hash algorithm is broken. You'd still have to create about $2^{128}$ hashes to find a collision after all, even if you take the birthday bound in - and remember that you'd have to perform a compare as well, although there are tricks to speed that up.

Instead the team that performs the analysis will find a weak spot and exploit it, sometimes requiring a lot of resources. This also means that if you create a collision that you are likely to be able to create more collisions using the same methodology.

If a relatively small amount of internal states are affected then it *may* be possible to fix the hash - hardened SHA-1 for instance is protected against the SHAttered attack. Of course, now that SHA-1 is shown to be weak, there is plenty of reason to migrate to e.g. SHA-256 anyway, and I haven't seen an uptake in hardened SHA-1 anywhere.

---

Even if you have only two inputs generating the same hash value you may be in trouble. Hashes internally operate block-by-block. If it is possible to find a collision then the next blocks will also be vulnerable. In other words, if you find $H'(B_1) = H'(B_2)$ then $H'(B_1 \| E) = H'(B_2 \| E)$ where $\|$ is concatenation. Note that extension $E$ may contain *any* data. So in that sense: if you find one collision for SHA-256 then you've found many collisions of messages that start with a particular block or blocks of data.

For SHA-3 the situation is a tad more complex (it depends if the internal state - i.e. the capacity of the used sponge - is identical before or after the final operation) but basically you'd still be in trouble.

---

If these kind of collisions are applicable to your protocol is another question. Schemes such as HMAC that rely on a hash function are not affected at all, as it doesn't require collision resistance from the configured hash function.

Comment: For SHA-3, the only internal state you need to be identical is the 'capacity bits'; the attacker can set the 'rate bits' on either message to whatever he wants (by selecting the message appropriately).